# Prove the equality conditions in the triangle inequality $S(A,B)\ge |S(A)-S(B)|$ for the von Neumann entropy

Tags: textbook-and-exercises, nielsen-and-chuang, information-theory, entropy, purification

The triangle inequality or Araki-Lieb inequality of the von Neumann entropy is
$$
S(A,B)\ge|S(A)-S(B)|
$$
this is proven by introducing a system $R$ which purifies systems $A$ and $B$. Applying subadditivity obtains $S(R)+S(A)\ge S(A,R)$.

$ABR$ is in a pure state $\implies $ $S(A,R)=S(B)$ and $S(R)=S(A,B)$. Therefore,

\begin{align}
S(R)+S(A)&=S(A,B)+S(A)\ge S(A,R)=S(B)\\
&\implies S(A,B)+S(A)\ge S(B)\\
&\implies S(A,B)\ge S(B)-S(A)
\end{align}

---

In [Page 516, Quantum Computation and Quantum Information by Nielsen and Chuang](http://mmrc.amss.cas.cn/tlb/201702/W020170224608149940643.pdf), Exercise 11.16 is given as

Let $ρ^{AB}=\sum_i λ_i|i\rangle\langle i|$ is a spectral decomposition for $ρ^{AB}$. Show that $S(A,B)=S(B)−S(A)$ if and only if the operators $ρ^A_i≡tr_B(|i\rangle\langle i|)$ have a common eigenbasis, and the $ρ^B_i≡tr_A(|i\rangle\langle i|)$ have orthogonal support.

How do I approach the problem, and are there any physical explanations for the equality conditions?

**My Attempt**

Klein inequality:$S(\rho||\sigma)=-S(\rho)-tr(\rho\log\sigma)= 0\implies \rho=\sigma$. Setting $\rho=\rho^{AR}$ and $\sigma=\rho^A\otimes\rho^R$ then
\begin{align}
S(\rho^{AR}||\rho^A\otimes\rho^R)&=-S(\rho^{AR})-tr(\rho^{AR}(\log\rho^A\otimes I_R+I_A\otimes\log\rho^R))\\
&=-S(\rho^{AR})-tr((\rho^{AR}(\log\rho^A\otimes I_R)+-tr((I_A\otimes\log\rho^R))\\
&=-S(\rho^{AR})-tr(\rho^A\log\rho^A)-tr(\rho^R\log\rho^R)\\
&=-S(\rho^{AR})+S(\rho^A)+S(\rho^R)\\
&=-S(AR)+S(A)+S(R)\\
\end{align}
we used $\log(\rho^A\otimes\rho^R)=\log\rho^A\otimes I_R+I_A\otimes\log\rho^R$ and $tr(\rho^{AR}(\sigma^A\otimes I))=tr(\rho^A\sigma^A)$, please check [Partial trace over a product of matrices - one factor is in tensor product form](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/5045/partial-trace-over-a-product-of-matrices-one-factor-is-in-tensor-product-form/31473#31473) for proof.

Therefore, $S(\rho^{AR}||\rho^A\otimes\rho^R)=0\implies S(A,R)= S(A)+S(R)\implies \rho^{AR}=\rho^A\otimes\rho^R$

$$
S(A,R)=S(A)+S(R)\implies S(A,B)=S(B)−S(A)\implies ρ^{AR}=ρ^A\otimes ρ^R\\
\rho^A=tr_B(\rho^{AB})=\sum_i λ_itr_B(|i\rangle\langle i|)\\
\rho^B=tr_A(\rho^{AB})=\sum_i λ_itr_A(|i\rangle\langle i|)\\
$$

Comment: what are the last equations in the post for? Are you asking about an "equality condition" in those equation or something else? Also, `> text` is really for quotes, not to highlight what you're asking (in fact, it achieves the exact opposite, making the most important part of the post less evident)

Comment: @glS Thanks for responding. The last three lines of equations are my attempt to show the given statement "$S(A,B)=S(B)−S(A)$ if and only if the operators $ρ^A_i≡tr_B(|i\rangle\langle i|)$ have a common eigenbasis, and the $ρ^B_i≡tr_A(|i\rangle\langle i|)$ have orthogonal support."

Comment: @glS I am asking about the equality condition of the triangle inequality for the von Neumann entropy, ie., $S(A,B)\ge |S(A)-S(B)|$

Comment: I feel like there might be a typo in the statement, or maybe I'm not understanding it correctly. As a counterexample, $\rho=\frac12(|\Psi\rangle\!\langle\Psi|+|\tilde\Psi\rangle\!\langle\tilde\Psi|)$ with $|\Psi\rangle=\frac1{\sqrt2}(|00\rangle+|11\rangle)$ and $|\tilde\Psi\rangle=\frac1{\sqrt2}(|22\rangle+|33\rangle)$. This is symmetric upon changing $A$ and $B$, thus $S(A)=S(B)$, but also $S(A,B)=1\neq S(B)-S(A)$, although it satisfies the assumptions b/c $\rho^A_1=\rho^B_1=\frac12(P_0+P_1)$ and $\rho^A_2=\rho^B_2=\frac12(P_2+P_3)$

Comment: @glS I believe the condition "$\rho^A_i$ have a common eigenbasis and $\rho^B_i$ have orthogonal support" should include all the vectors $|i\rangle$ forming the complete basis.  In your counter example, $\{|i\rangle\}$ should include $|e_3\rangle=(|00\rangle-|11\rangle)/\sqrt2, |e_4\rangle =  \ldots$.  And in this case, $\rho^B_1 = \rho^B_3$ and they do not have orthogonal support.

Comment: There seems a problem with my interpretation as well.  Consider the example $\rho = \left|00\rangle\langle00\right|$.  Since it's a pure state, $S(\rho) = 0$.  And because the two systems are symmetrical, $S(A) = S(B)$, thus $S(A,B) = S(B)-S(A)$.  If we consider the complete set of basis $\{|00\rangle, |01\rangle, |10\rangle, |11\rangle\}$, $\mbox{tr}_A|00\rangle\langle00| = \mbox{tr}_A|10\rangle\langle10|$ and they do not have orthogonal support.